# GPIOZERO LEDBoard => Lights on when starting PI

Tags: ssh, toggle, light

I am just new to coding.

I set up an Lightsystem, which has 6 buttons (each with an LED-Indicator which is on when the Light is on) and also 6 Lights.

Now I am using GPIOZERO for an easy coding.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gpiozero import LEDBoard, Button
from signal import pause

leds1 = LEDBoard(13,23)
leds2 = LEDBoard(19,24)
leds3 = LEDBoard(16,25)
leds4 = LEDBoard(26,5)
leds5 = LEDBoard(20,6)
leds6 = LEDBoard(21,12)

button1 = Button(14)
button2 = Button(15)
button3 = Button(17)
button4 = Button(18)
button5 = Button(27)
button6 = Button(22)

button1.when_pressed = leds1.toggle
button2.when_pressed = leds2.toggle
button3.when_pressed = leds3.toggle
button4.when_pressed = leds4.toggle
button5.when_pressed = leds5.toggle
button6.when_pressed = leds6.toggle

pause()
```

This script starts as soon as my raspberry is started.
But using the LEDBoard function is forcing the Lights to be active.
But I don't want them to be active.

Is there a way to start the script with the lights turned off?

When I am using

```
leds1.off()
```

right infront of

```
button1.when_pressed = leds1.toggle
```

the Lights are off and I am not able to turn them on again.

The second thing is, I want a separate script, which is started via SSH, and this should toggle the lights also.
But when I use the code like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gpiozero import LEDBoard, Button
leds1 = LEDBoard(13,23)
leds1.toggle
```

in a second script which started via SSH, I won't be able to use my buttons to toggle my lights again.

Is there a way to do that?